# Hide border behind text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, border

I want to hide a part of the border that goes behind my text and around my container. I currently have this: 
[image]

I just need the line behind LOG IN gone and a few pixels behind/in front of it.

What is the best way of doing this?

My current code:

HTML:

```
<div class="login">
    <h1 class="header">Log in</h1>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-6">
            <form>
                <input type="email" name="emailadres" class="form-control" placeholder="Emailadres">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
// vars
$login-form-background-color: #f7f4f1;
$login-form-color: #00726d;
.login {
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  background-color: $login-form-background-color;
  border: 3px solid $login-form-color;
  border-radius: 5px;
  & h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: -3rem 0 0 0;
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-family: $font-AnimatedGothicLight;
    color: $login-form-color;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  & form {
    padding: 3.5rem 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `z-index` with a `div` in between the text and the form `container`? You might be able to get what you want if you give the middle `div` a `background-color` of either the `container` or the `body`. You would just need to align the middle `div` either above or below the form `container`'s top border.